# Voice Recognition module V3.1 and Bluetooth module (HC-05) not working together (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, voice-recognition, hc-05

The Bluetooth module(HC-05)and voice recognition module (V 3.1) work individually just fine with Arduino Uno but when I try to run them together then the one of them stops working that is the voice module stops working. I have't been able to figure out why. My code is as follows:

```cpp
# include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "VoiceRecognitionV3.h"

VR myVR(2,3);    // 2:RX 3:TX 
uint8_t buf[64];
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(4,5); //for Bluetooth module RX FOLLOWD BY TX

void printSignature(uint8_t *buf, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (buf[i] > 0x19 && buf[i] < 0x7F) {
            Serial.write(buf[i]);
        }
    } 
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(A4,OUTPUT);// for VCC of voice module
    digitalWrite(A4,HIGH);
    myVR.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    myVR.load((uint8_t)0);  //loading the data of voice module
    myVR.load((uint8_t)1);
    myVR.load((uint8_t)2); 
    myVR.load((uint8_t)3); 
    myVR.load((uint8_t)4); 
    bluetooth.begin(9600);       
}

String one;

void loop() {
    int ret = myVR.recognize(buf, 50);
    if (bluetooth.available() > 0) {
        one  = bluetooth.readString();
        Serial.println(one);
    }
    if (ret > 0) {
        Serial.print("Voice module said  ");
        printSignature(buf+4, buf[3]); //priting the signature of command
        Serial.println(""); //for new line
    }
}
```

1)The problem is in communication because when I remove myVR.begin(9600) then bluetooth works and voice module does not.

2)when I remove bluetooth.begin(9600) then voice module works and bluetooth does not.

together they are not working ,only one works.

Answer (score 1):

`VoiceRecognitionV3` inherits `SoftwareSerial`. It is possible to have multiple `SoftwareSerial` instances in a program. However, only one can receive data at a time. So, you want to switch between your ports with `listen()` ([doc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialListen)).

```cpp
portOne.listen(); 
ret = portOne.read();

portTwo.listen(); 
ret = portTwo.read();
```

The Arduino site has an example. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TwoPortReceive